# Why does piping `mysql` to 'tail' change the output format?

Tags: pipe, mysql, tail

When I view the result of a `SELECT` with MySQL Workbench, it's correct with one single **\**

```
max@host 10:13:58: ~$ mysql -h db-master.domain.local -uuser -ppw db -e '
>                 SELECT
>                 DISTINCT i.filesourceregexp
>                 FROM db.ImportLogFiles i'

+------------------------------------------------+
| filesourceregexp                               |
+------------------------------------------------+
| ^[0-9]{8}_1062355673_merge_google_pbn\.csv$    |
| ^[0-9]{8}_8026062435_merge_google_pbn\.csv$    |
| ^[0-9]{8}_1062355673_store_visits_report\.csv$ |
+------------------------------------------------+

max@host 10:14:10: ~$ mysql -h db-master.domain.local -uuser -ppw db -e '
                SELECT
                DISTINCT i.filesourceregexp
                FROM db.ImportLogFiles i' | tail -n +2
^[0-9]{8}_1062355673_merge_google_pbn\\.csv$
^[0-9]{8}_8026062435_merge_google_pbn\\.csv$
^[0-9]{8}_1062355673_store_visits_report\\.csv$
max@host 10:14:19: ~$
```

I have these options in `my.cnf`:

```
[client] 
host = db-master 
user = user 
password = pass 
default-character-set=utf8
```

Why does piping the result through `tail` change the output/string? (note the double `\`).

Comment: You get the same output if you pipe through another command, right? For example `mysql ... | head` or `mysql ... | grep 8`?

Comment: Thanks for improving my English. `head` and `grep 802` do also double the **\\** `max@host 10:50:48: ~$ mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.55, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3`

Comment: which tail are you using ? can you share the output of `tail --version`

Comment: @amisax my tail is `tail (GNU coreutils) 8.23` but i have the same problem with grep or head

Comment: my bash is `GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` and `uname -a`results: `Linux host 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: The process is likely using `tcgetattr()`, `isatty()`, etc; to detect where its output is going to do conditional output generation. You could always write an `LD_PRELOAD` rootkit library to overcome this.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It's not `tail`, it's the piping.

`mysql` uses a tabular with ASCII boxing output format when its stdout is a terminal device, when it's intended for a user, and reverts to a *scripting* format when it's not, like when it's a pipe or a regular file.

You'd see the same *different* format with

```
mysql... | cat
```

or

```
mysql > file; cat file
```

See also the `-r`/`--raw`, `-s`/`--silent`, `-B`/`--batch`, `-N`/`--skip-column-names`/`--column-names=0`, `-H`/`--html`, `-t`/`--table`... that affect the output format.

If you want the tabular output even when the output doesn't go to a terminal device, add the `-t` option:

```
mysql -t ... | tail -n +2
```

But if the point is to remove the header line, just use `-N`, with or without `-t`.

Here to get the values from the database as raw as possible and without header, I'd use:

```
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/some/protected/file/with/credentials \
      --batch --raw --skip-column-names -e 'select...' database
```

That is:

- not expose the password in the output of `ps` by passing the credentials in a file instead (like your `my.cnf`) with `--defaults-extra-file`.
- use the *batch* mode to avoid the tabular output (and acknowledge the fact that we are actually batching it which may have other implications).
- `--raw` to avoid the *escaping*. Assuming the values don't contain newlines as otherwise the output could not be post-processed reliably.
- `--skip-column-names` to remove the header line.

Comment: the options `-r --column-names=0` solved my problem, tanks

Comment: This is the same reason that `ls` output is put into columns when the output goes to a terminal, but is a single column when writing to a pipe or file.